# LINQ "where" with parameter

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I'm sure that it's rookie mistake, but I can't find an answer by myself.

```
public class Database : DataContext 
{
    public Table<Record> RecordTable;
    public Database(string connection) : base(connection) {}
}

[Table(Name = "RecordsTable")]
public class Record
{
    [Column( IsPrimaryKey = true, CanBeNull = false)]
    public int codedID;
}

// inside some class
private void ReadTestData(Database openedDatabase, int expectedValue)
{
    Table<Record> rec = openedDatabase.GetTable<Record>();
    var q =
        from a in rec
        where (GetMonth == expectedValue)   // <--- that line doesn't work
        select a;

    foreach (var b in q) { System.Console.WriteLine("something"); }
}

static Expression<Func<Record, int>> GetMonth = a => a.codedID/10000;

public static int DecodeMonth(int codedID)
{
    int month = codedID/10000;
    //(...)
    return month;
}
```

I'd like to call **DecodeMonth** function and compare it's return value with expectedValue. How should I do that?

I've done some research and managed to run code like that:

```
var q = openedDatabase.RecordTable.Where(GetMonthBool);

static Expression<Func<Record, bool>> GetMonthBool = a => (a.codedID/10000 == 1);
```

but expectedValue is hardcoded as "1" - and that doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a method that creates the expression like this

```
private Expression<Func<Record, bool>> GetMonthBoolFunc(int value)
{
    return a => (a.codedID/10000 == value); 
}

var q = openedDatabase.RecordTable.Where(GetMonthBoolFunc(1));
```